# How to get text box values to parameters in Button OnClick Function?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I need to get txtRemarks & txtCost textbox values into two parameters on Button OnClick method. So that I can pass those parameters to the method in my controller. Let me explain a little further. I have two text boxes which were created outside the model. Below I have mentioned them.

```
@Html.Editor("txtRemarks", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker", @placeholder = "N/A" } })

@Html.Editor("txtCost", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker", @type = "number", @placeholder = "0.00" } })
```

I need to get their values to two parameters in Button Onclick event. Below is the click event and the Button. I need to get those parameter values to my ActionResult Method **ServiceDetails** in controller **ServiceHeaders**

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val(),?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
```

All I need a way to Connect `?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val()` and `?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()`. I can pass one parameter by using `?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val()`or`?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()`. But I do not know how to get both at once. This is where I need your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

You can link the parameters such as :
`localhost?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val() + '&Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()`.

While doing a HTTP GET, you can set parameters with `...?var1=test1&var2=test2&var3=test3` etc

See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) for more info.

Note: you could also considere using HTTP POST for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The link is badly built. To concatenate parameters you must use `&`. Try with this

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val() + '&Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove the onClick() from the button.

2) Add an ajax call for the button click as follows

```
$('#btnAddtoGrid').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new{Remark = ' + 
            $('#txtRemarks').val() + ', Cost = ' + $('#txtCost').val()+'}) %>',
            success: function (
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank You. I could get an additional idea of doing it   :)

Answer (score 0):

Client side.

```
 $('#btnAddtoGrid').on("click",function () {
           $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                        data: '{newremark : "' + $('#txtRemarks').val() + '" , cost: "' + $('#txtCost').val() + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
        });
```

server side.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string newremark,string cost)
    {       
        return Json(newremark);
    }
```